# Multiple classes on keyup jquery

Tags: jquery, class, event-handling, onkeyup

I have a function that I want to execute on `keyup` for 2 different `class` of `textfields`.
The code below works well when only one class is assigned to `keyup` but when I add a second `class` it works but there is a lot of lag. Either `class` by itself works fine so I assume I added the second `class` to the event handler improperly. The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".class1").each(function() {

        //!!!!!!! .class2 here adds lag !!!!!!!!!!
        $('.class1,.class2').keyup(function(){
            myFunction1();

        });
    });

    $(".class2").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            myFunction2();
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears you are wiring up too many events - hence the lag.
You also don't need the .each, that's for iterating each element.
Try simplifying as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.class1,.class2').keyup(function(){
        myFunction1();
        if ($(this).hasClass('class2')) {
            myFunction2();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 as I'd probably do it this way but I did offer an alternative depending if the user didn't want an extensive if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can add two separate events and call your functions.  It is similar to the other answer and probably just depends on style.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/wzEJc/

Example code:

```
function myFunction1(el) {
    el.addClass('mclass1');
};

function myFunction2(el) {
    el.addClass('mclass2');
};


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.class1').keyup(function(){
        myFunction1($(this));    
    });
    $('.class2').keyup(function(){
        myFunction1($(this));
        myFunction2($(this));    
    });

});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative! It's nice to see different ways to get a deeper understanding! Hats off to you!

Answer (score 1):

You're binding quite a bunch of event handlers where you could just let the event bubble and capture it later on:

```
 $('body').on('keyup', '.class1, .class2', myFunction1);
 $('body').on('keyup', '.class2', myFunction2);
```

Comment: This is interesting, I can't get it to work right but I bet I'm missing something, I will mess with it, thanks for the alternative info!